# C# - 2d matrix - is guess left/right/up/down of point

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, matrix, multidimensional-array

Using a 2d array of buttons implemented and placed on a form.

```
Button[,] tmpButton = new Button[x, y];
private void DrawGrid()
{
     int ButtonWidth = 48;
     int ButtonHeight = 48;
     int start_x = 88;
     int start_y = 200;

     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
         {
             tmpButton[i, j] = new Button();
             tmpButton[i, j].Top = start_x + (i * ButtonHeight);
             tmpButton[i, j].Left = start_y + (j * ButtonWidth);
             tmpButton[i, j].Width = ButtonWidth;
             tmpButton[i, j].Height = ButtonHeight;
             tmpButton[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(BTN_Grid_Click);
             this.Controls.Add(tmpButton[i, j]);
         }
     }
}
```

If a random location (x,y) is set `true` within the grid with the intention of guessing (by clicking on the surrounding grid buttons) it's location. If the location is `!true` it should return `left` `right` `up` `down` pointing to the random location we set earlier. If the `true` location is up and left, it should return whichever it is closest too.

What would be the best way to implement something like this?

This is getting close, but something I can't see is off a bit ...

```
public String GetDirection()
{
    int xd = Guess.X - Clue.X;
    int yd = Guess.Y - Clue.Y;

    if(Math.Abs(xd) <= Math.Abs(yd))
        return (xd <= 0) ? "Left" : "Right";
    else
        return (yd <= 0) ? "Down" : "Up";
}
```

Here is a visual representation of what is happening ...

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?'

Comment: Have you tried some approach by yourself and had any problems with it?

Comment: You have two coordinates. Get their difference, xd=x1-x2, yd=y1-y2. Based on absolute values decide which coordinate you'll use, and then based on sign decide the actual direction.

Comment: @dumbdumbbadatthis Not allot. Previously I was using a simple solution where if `guessCount % 2 == 0` either place left or right based on the x values `else` place up or down based on y values. But this solution has drawbacks if guessCount is even, it would place an up or down arrow, even if it was on the same row. Tried to consider a way to use distance formula `(x1,y1)^2 + (x2,y2)^2` but not sure how that would help in this scenario.

Comment: @Dialecticus Which coordinate to use would be based on the lowest absolute value, and if negative `(left/down)` or if positive `(right/up)` ... Is my logic here correct?

Comment: Correct. Try it, see if it works.

Comment: @Dialecticus It's really close but still wrong. I updated my OP with my attempt. Any clue what might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so you had most of it right however you made a easy mistake.  When you create the buttons you're rendering from left to right then top to bottom which creates the height as the x position then the width as the y position.  So when you go and correlate the guess to the correct position you forget that you did this and assume x is the width.

Here's my implementation which fixed this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UpDownLeftRight {

    public partial class Form1 : Form {

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }

        public int[] winner = new int[2];
        public Button[,] tmpButton = new Button[10, 10];
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int ButtonWidth = 48;
            int ButtonHeight = 48;
            int start_x = 0;
            int start_y = 0;
            winner = new int[] { r.Next(0, 10), r.Next(0, 10) };
            this.Size = new Size((ButtonWidth * 11), (ButtonHeight * 11));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    tmpButton[i, j] = new Button();
                    tmpButton[i, j].Left = start_x + (i * ButtonWidth);
                    tmpButton[i, j].Top = start_y + (j * ButtonHeight);
                    tmpButton[i, j].Width = ButtonWidth;
                    tmpButton[i, j].Height = ButtonHeight;
                    tmpButton[i, j].Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 17);
                    tmpButton[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(BTN_Grid_Click);
                    this.Controls.Add(tmpButton[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }

        public void BTN_Grid_Click(object o, EventArgs e) {
            int[] guess = new int[2];
            for (int i = 0; i != tmpButton.GetLength(1); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j != tmpButton.GetLength(0); j++) {
                    if (tmpButton[i, j] == o) {
                        guess = new int[] { i, j };
                    }
                }
            }
            int xDist = guess[0] - winner[0];
            int yDist = guess[1] - winner[1];
            string possible = "˂˃˄˅";
            if (xDist > 0) { possible = possible.Replace("˃", ""); }
            if (xDist < 0) { possible = possible.Replace("˂", ""); }
            if (xDist == 0) { possible = possible.Replace("˂", ""); possible = possible.Replace("˃", ""); }
            if (yDist > 0) { possible = possible.Replace("˅", ""); }
            if (yDist < 0) { possible = possible.Replace("˄", ""); }
            if (yDist == 0) { possible = possible.Replace("˄", ""); possible = possible.Replace("˅", ""); }
            ((Button)o).Text = possible;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to have only one arrow display instead of 2 like you have here. The direction to be shown should be calculated by whichever is "closest" to the clue.

Comment: Which should take priority if both are equal?

Comment: You know what...I can actually modify the images to point to the corners too and use those if they are equal. Never crossed my mind how easy it would be to get arrows to point diagonal too.